# WPF binding to DataGrid - displaying data

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a little problem, I know its probably trivial.

Here is my car collection :

```
public class CarCollection : ObservableCollection<Car>
{
    public CarCollection()
    {
        Add(new Car("BMW", "X6", 250000, "Berlin"));
        Add(new Car("BMW", "X4", 170000, "Berlin"));
        Add(new Car("Audi", "A4", 55000, "Warszawa"));
        Add(new Car("Audi", "A5", 75000, "Blabla"));
        Add(new Car("Audi", "A6", 120000, "Berlin"));
        Add(new Car("Seat", "Ibiza", 22000, "Barcelona"));
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public Car()
    { }

    public Car(string company, string model, int price, string city)
    {

    }
}
```

And i want to bind this to my DataGrid :

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGrid"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Window.DataContext>
       <local:CarCollection/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   <Grid>
       <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

The data is loaded to my DataGrid because I can see Columns names and 6 rows, but they are fully empty and have no idea what im doing wrong :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to **set the properties in constructor**.

```
public Car(string company, string model, int price, string city)
{
    Company = company;
    Model = model;
    Price = price;
    City = city;
}
```

Comment: ohhh... kill me, looks like time to sleep :D thank you so much ! :)

Comment: This might be the correct answer, but @RohitVats: can you explain how can the DataGrid visualize CarCollection data without having any binding to it explicitly specified?

Comment: You're welcome mate. Happens sometimes (looking over the obvious things).

Comment: @supertopi - DataContext of window is set to an instance of CarCollection in XAML which will be inherited by DataGrid and since ItemsSource is binded to DataContext via this `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`, it will pick the CarCollection data. Hope it is clear.

Comment: OK. So if the DataContext would consist of multiple variables e.g. CarCollection and BikeCollection, we should specify which variable I would bind my DataGrid to? e.g. `ItemsSource="{Binding CarCollection}"`

Comment: Yes that's how binding works. If you want to bind to some property inside DataContext, you specify `Path` in binding for that like you did for CarCollection in the comment.

Comment: @supertopi - You're welcome. This might come handy for you to learn more about it - [Binding cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf).

Comment: @Rohit But about the supertopi question, is it possible to create 2 instances in DataContext? supertopi has written "DataContext would consist of multiple variables e.g. CarCollection and BikeCollection" is it even possible ? When I try to make another line in <window.datacontex> i got error "Error the property 'DataContext' is set more than once"

Comment: No, you can set only one object as `DataContext`. Wrap the two collections into one class (of course expose two collections from it) and set DataContext to the object of the wrapped class. Then you can bind to the collection which you want.

Comment: You have made all this clear, thank you once again ! :)